# Replicate Function

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to rewrite the code for a function replicate which repeats the first item of a list n times and then returns the list with the repeated first item and the rest of the list. Here is the original function:

```
(check-expect (replicateone 1 '(stays the same)) '(stays the same))
(check-expect (replicateone 0 '(hello bye)) '(bye))
(check-expect (replicateone 3 
    '(repeat second third ))
              '(repeat repeat repeat second third))

(define (replicateone n nonemptylist)
  (cond [(zero? n) (rest nonemptylist)]
        [else 
    (cons (first nonemptylist) (replicateone (sub1 n) nonemptylist))]))
```

This is what I have right now, but it's not working.

```
(define (iterate f n x)
  (cond
    [(zero? n) x]
    [else (iterate f (sub1 n) (f x))]))

(define (replicateone n nonemptylist)
 (iterate (λ (x) (list x x)) n nonemptylist))
```

I'm trying to do this in ISL+ without all the recursion, but I'm unsure how to write the iterate function using new techniques. I feel like this would use foldr, but I'm not too sure.

Any help would be great since I'm still learning.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it with `iterate`:

```
(define (replicateone n lst)
  (iterate (lambda (x) (cons (first lst) x)) n (rest lst)))
```

Here's "an" implementation of `iterate` that doesn't use direct recursion and does run correctly with ISL+, but, it's (intentionally) obfuscated. You'll have fun trying to figure out how it works. ;-)

```
(define (iterate f n x)
  (foldl (compose f second list) x (make-list n #f)))
```

Comment: Thank you, that definitely helps. Is there a way to write iterate so it wasn't recursive using functions in ISL+?

Comment: Sure, I added an implementation of such. It's quite cryptic though (intentionally; there are less cryptic ways to write the same code), so have fun figuring out how it works!

Comment: What is #f? It doesn't seem to work in ISL+. Also the compose function takes two variables, but you have three down.

Comment: According to http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/intermediate.html, `#f` does indeed work. It worked for me when I tested. In any case, you can use anything else instead, such as 0, `empty`, etc. It's just that in Scheme, we conventionally use `#f` for an "invalid" or "unused" value.

Comment: It showed up as green, so I figured it was a comment code. What is # called, so I can look it up? Also compose takes two variables, but you have three.

Comment: As for the `compose`, it worked for me when I tested too (both in `#lang htdp/isl` and `#lang htdp/isl+`). But you can replace that with `(compose f (compose second list))`, or, to be less cryptic, `(lambda (_ r) (f r))`.

Comment: You should search for `#f` in the page I linked you! It's the false value.

Comment: @Ryan `#f` is the same as `false`

Comment: Can you rewrite that compose function interms of lambda. The second part (make-list..) can be a list of any n values long, but I can't see how compose relates to that because we have never used it.

Comment: @Ryan: Please read my second-to-last comment for the lambda version.

Comment: @soegaard Of course, but its main relevance is as an unused value, since (as you can see in the lambda I posted earlier) it gets plugged in as `_`.

Comment: I remembered wrong. I thought the syntax `#f` was left out of ISL (and that's why Ryan asked), I see now that that is actually do work.